# problems with pulp (python)

Tags: python, pulp

I have a problem with pulp, I'm trying to convert this constraint

```
∑_iϵN Xijkz+Vjkz+Ujkz = nsjk*sjz                     ∀ j ϵ J , ∀ z ϵ S , ∀ k ϵ K .

for i in N:
    prob += lpSum(X[(i,j,k,z) ]+V[(j,k,z)]+U[(j,k,z)]
    for j in J 
        for k in K 
            for z in S2)==(ns[k][j]*s1[k][j])
```

But I'm not sure it's fair, I do not have any kind of error, however, the objective function is 0

Comment: What is pulp? Its some library?

Comment: answer alone, can be of help to someone
for j in J :
 for k in K:
  for z in S:
   prob += sum(X[(i,j,k,z) ] for i in N )+V[(j,k,z)]+U[(j,k,z)] ==ns[k][j]*s1[z][j]